# Google Cloud Platform BigQuery - Cannot Add Table "Unexpected Error"

Tags: google-chrome, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Everytime I try to add a table to this empty dataset, BigQuery keeps throwing
"Unexpected Error       tracking number: xxxxxxxxxxxxx", with two options: Send Feedback and Close. I've used the Send Feedback option several times now, and I really cannot move forward in this class without being able to create basic datasets on BigQuery.

Comment: Did you check if your user has the sufficient permissions? Do you have access do Cloud Logging? If you do, check in the logs if there are more details of the error.

Comment: What's your permission? How do you perform the operation? Did you try with the cli?

Comment: I did not perform any calculations or write functions. Our instruction was to create a dataset, click the create table option. From there, we are instructed to click upload and add the .csv file from desktop. This worked smoothly until this week. The “unexpected error” is thrown at the end when I choose the file I want to upload and click “create table”. 

I tried using a different laptop, as well as different google accounts, and even different datasets.